# Type from object's values

Tags: typescript

I've recently run into a problem of strictly specified allowed strings to be passed into a function:

```js
type TypesList = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

function send(type: TypesList): void {};

send('foo'); // Ok
send('error'); // Error
```

Function listed above will only accept one of the three values of `TypedList`. What I'm basically trying to do is to provide type union from constant's values so in the case of future modifications I will not be required to update value everywhere.

```js
const types = {
  foo: 'foo1',
  bar: 'bar2'
};

// Will check for "foo | bar" but I need "foo1 | bar2"
type TypesList = keyof typeof types; 

function send(type: TypesList): void {};
send(types.foo); // Invalid
```

I'm aware of the fact that I could just simply duplicate values from the constant or check in the function but I'm looking for a more cleaner and robust way to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String enums are available since TypeScript 2.4.0, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

```
enum Type {
    foo = 'foo1',
    bar = 'bar2'
}

function send(type: Type): void {};
send(Type.foo);
```

The enum compiles to a dictionary that maps the key name to the value, for use in run-time. If you don't need that, just make it a `const enum`.

---

Other than that, it is currently not possible to define a type as the union of all values of an object, even when that object is constant. 
Making a union of strings would be the usual way to go, since the main purpose of making a union of string literal types is to create an enum-like structure with string as their data type. Fortunately, we now have string enums.

As you would be using well-defined constants everywhere, there is also a chance that you do not need such a union type. In that case, you could enclose constants in a namespace and let functions take an ordinary `string`:

```
namespace Types {
    export const foo = "foo1";
    export const bar = "bar2";
}

function send(type: string): void {};
send(Types.foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @E_net4! I'll be waiting for the 2.4 version release then. The second option does not really work for me because I want a code to be self-documented and narrow consumer to a specific list of strings.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It seems that `2.4.0` is already released on GitHub and npm, although not with the `latest` tag. It should be safe to use it now by specifying this version explicitly. There's also the nightly version `2.5.0` in the `next` tag.

Comment: Right, but since it's still a release candidate I will avoid using it for now.